# Combination of group by, order and distinct

Tags: sql, group-by

My query

```
 SELECT a, b, c
 FROM table
 WHERE
    a > 0 AND a < 4 AND
    b IN (
        SELECT z FROM table2
        WHERE x = y
    )
```

produces the following output:

```
A B C
1 1 Car
1 1 Keyboard
1 2 Apple
1 3 Frog
2 1 Carrot
2 2 Parrot
3 1 Doll
```

what I want is the following output

```
A B C
1 1 Car
2 1 Carrot
3 1 Doll
```

So basically for every A, the lowest B and associated C (as well as other columns).

I tried various join types, group bys, but I am running out of ideas.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Do a join on a subquery:

```
 SELECT a, b, c
 FROM table t1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT a a2, MIN(b) b2 FROM table GROUP BY a) t2
     ON t1.a = t2.a2 AND t1.b = t2.b2
 WHERE
    a > 0 AND a < 4 AND
    b IN (
        SELECT z FROM table2
        WHERE x = y
    )
```

Comment: Thank you. The only problem left now is that b is actually a column that is computed e.g. b = k * l, so I can't do a b = b. Even if that wasn't the case I can't do t1.b = t2.b, because it is an invalid identifier.

Comment: Either post your current query as-is so those details are evident or figure out how to adapt the answer (e.g. `t1.k * t1.l = t2.k * t2.l`)`

Comment: I adapted the answer, but for some reason I don't get the minimum b per a, but all bs per a.

Comment: I just tested it, this is true even when the multiplication is not part of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Top N Apply

```
SELECT a, b, c
 FROM table
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT top 1 z 
                FROM table2
                WHERE x = y
                order by z ) t2
 WHERE a > 0 AND a < 4 AND
```